# Load Image from Embedded resource WP8 / C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am trying to load an image from an Embedded resource in a windows phone application

Here is my project setup:

Module1 = Phone Application

Module2 = ClassLibrary.dll

Module1 calls Module2 to create all of the data objects for the phone app.

When Module2 is creating the objects, I wanted to load an image from a resource.

The resource is "Default.png" and saved in the "Images" directory ( Build Action = Embedded Resource, Copy to Output Directory = Copy Always)

The code I am using produces an exception

```
ex = {"The request is not supported. "}
```

Here is the code:

```
private void LoadImage()
{
  Assembly curAssembly = null; 

  curAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

  string [] names = curAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

  // names[0] = "Storage.Images.Default.png"
  // so I know I am using the correct name 

  Stream resStream = curAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Storage.Images.Default.png");

  BitmapImage bitMapImage = new BitmapImage();

  try
  {
    bitMapImage.SetSource(resStream);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
  }
}
```

Can you help a newbie out?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...

The name I was using to load the resource was wrong...

Using the name from the array returned in this call

```
string [] names = curAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
```

And it works flawlessly

Answer (score 0):

Steps to get that working:

**First Appraoch**

1. Right-click on your project in VS and choose "**Add New Item**"
2. From "General" tab choose "**Resources File**"
3. Open that **resource_file.resx** which you just added to your project and choose "**Add Existing Item**" and then choose your image.
4. Then then in your LoadImage method, do this:

   **private void LoadImage()

   {

        Drawing.Bitmap bitMapImage = resource_file.name_of_your_image;

   }**

Note: In this code, I assumed that the name you choose for your resource file is "resource_file"

**Second Approach**

```
System.Resources.ResourceManager rm = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(this.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Name + ".resource_file", this.GetType().Assembly);
System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp= (System.Drawing.Bitmap)rm.GetObject("Baba");
```

or use can use System.Resources.ResourceReader and other approaches

Comment: Thank you for the approaches... I will give those a try... but they don't answer my question as to why I can't load a resource, even though the resource is within the module, as indicated by GetManifestResourceNames ??